# error when installing from pipfile.lock in docker

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, django-channels

I am trying to use docker in the project. It was working fine unless i used django channels and Pillow. Below was my working configuration

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# set working directory which will be inside ubuntu
WORKDIR /code

#### Install a dependency ####
# install psycopg2
RUN echo "https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/alpine/v3.9/main" > /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/alpine/v3.9/community" >>/etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev \
    && pip3 install psycopg2-binary \
    && apk del .tmp-build-deps

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* /code/
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /code/entrypoint.sh
COPY . /code/

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/entrypoint.sh"]
```

my pipfile is

```
[packages]
django = "*"
"psycopg2-binary" = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
djangorestframework-jwt = "*"
djoser = "*"
graphene-django = "*"
django-cors-headers = "*"
django-graphql-social-auth = "*"
django-money = "*"
django-mptt = "*"
pillow = "*"
channels = "*"
channels-redis = "*"
```

the error i get is something like this

[image]

if i remove the pillow, channels and channels-redis from pipfile, it works. How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, errors like this are often the result of a transitive, native dependency that's missing. From the error message, it looks like `cffi` won't install. That library depends on an OS package `libffi`, so you should just need add `libffi-dev` to the packages installed by `apk`.

I tested this manually, by starting a docker container and installing the failed libs manually. Via `docker run --rm -it python:3.7-alpine /bin/sh`, then `pip install ...` or `apk add ...`

Comment: its still giving me same error. I did `RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev libffi-dev` but still same issue

Comment: any update on this issue? it would be great you if share the solution to this issue you  if knew how ;)